# Search Display Controller in iOS 7. Missing bar when the keyboard appears

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, uisearchbar

I have created a small app Recipe Book and decided to add a Search Display Controller. Problem is that when I clicked on the searchbar, the keyboard appears and overshadows my searchbar, but I can see it. And when I start to input some letters (example egg, I have this cell in my tableView) searchTableView appear, my cell appears, but the search bar has gone.

[image: keyboard overshadowing the search bar]

What am I doing wrong? It works great in iOS 6.0 or iOS 6.1.

Comment: Please provide a small example of your code that demonstrates what you've tried and exhibits the problem.

Comment: Whatever this problem is about, know that the search bar in iOS 7 is bugged. See http://petersteinberger.com/blog/2013/fixing-uisearchdisplaycontroller-on-ios-7/

Comment: thanks for you answers very much! it was important to me to understand whether this is a bug or just my mistake. because i have just follow the instructions in tutorial on one website) but i don't understand yet the code from the link above)) it's hard for me for this moment))

Comment: P.S. how the search bar works on my iPhone on iOS7 if it has bugs? example address book or other search in app

Comment: Probably this might be due to status bar issue in iOS 7. You can set frame of SearchBar (say +40px) when textBegin of SearchBar happens. This should bring SearchBar to same position when text is begin editing.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you come up with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a bug in IOS7. I got rid of the problem. Not sure what finally solved it, but here is what I did.
I suggest you to:

- Remove the SearchDisplayController from the storyboard, if you are
  using a storyboard.
- Check that you do not have already a searchBar property linked with
  the searchBar in the storyboard.

[image]

- Add the SearchDisplayController again to the storyboard.. (all the
  delegates and datasources and connections are already set up) (just
  need to put the  in the code)

if you have implemented the delegate methods, that is all that is need to be done. No additional searchBar allocated, you can use self.searchDisplayController.searchBar directly!

Comment: Your solution is not working properly. It doesn't bind with table view and that's why does not overlapping.